# PHP include file, negative match lines, output file

Tags: php, awk, grep

Using an intermediary php file, I wish to call an existing php file (get.php).  get.php outputs an m3u (text) file.  Before simply sending the m3u file to the browser file, I need to remove certain lines.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('get.php'); /*Receives an m3u file*/
$output = ob_get_contents();
$list = preg_replace('Remove.*keyphrase.*\n.*\n' , '' , $output ); /*Also removes the line after the line containing keyphrase*/
echo $list; /*Output as m3u file*/
?>
```

Note:  I realize there are several problems above.  I am beginner level.

The include file is php but the browser downloads an m3u playlist file.

Then, remove line and following line of received m3u file matching keyphrase string.

Finally, output put the resulting data as m3u file (file name same as received at include).

Sample file

```
This line remains
Remove this line because it has the keyphrase.
Remove this line because it is the line after.
This line also remains
```

Output file

```
This line remains
This line also remains
```

---

This is what I ended up using:

```
<?php
$file = file('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/get.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$list = preg_grep("/keyphrase/",$file,PREG_GREP_INVERT);

// to have Array
//print_r($list);

// back to string
echo implode("",$list);
?>
```

I could not get preg_grep() to match two lines (even with /s or /m) with the most basic tests.  If you need just one line then the above is great.  If you need more than one line you will need to match using regex OR or manipulate the input file before the above.

Comment: `grep` expects data from stdin or from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_grep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) - Reads entire file into an array

If set to `PREG_GREP_INVERT`, this function returns the elements of the input array that do not match the given pattern.

```
[akshay@c1 tmp]$ cat get.php 
This line remains
Remove this line because it has the keyphrase.
Remove this line because it is the line after the keyphrase.
This line also remains

[akshay@c1 tmp]$ grep -v keyphrase get.php 
This line remains
This line also remains

[akshay@c1 tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php
$file = file('get.php');
$list = preg_grep("/keyphrase/",$file,PREG_GREP_INVERT );

// to have Array
print_r($list); 

// back to string
echo implode("",$list);
?>

[akshay@c1 tmp]$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => This line remains

    [3] => This line also remains

)
This line remains
This line also remains
```

If you prefer `shell_exec()` then you just need below

```
[akshay@c1 tmp]$ cat test-shell.php 
<?php
$list = shell_exec('grep -v "keyphrase" get.php'); 
echo $list; 
?>

[akshay@c1 tmp]$ php test-shell.php 
This line remains
This line also remains
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your -v match works because I foolishly put the word in both lines 2 and 3.  I have adjusted the the sample file.  

Also, thanks to Ron, then you, I took a stab at preg_replace in the question.

The other thing is this.  That when I call the test.php file, I will pass parameters in the URL.  Will those pass when calling get using file()?  The values pass to get.php when I use include.

Comment: @dyna in current context `get.php` is just filename, however `file()` also supports `file('http://www.example.com?par1=foo&par2=bar')` , please read on [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: @AkshayHedge I implemented the code.  It is displaying the source of get.php file in the browser.  I realize this might not have been clear, so I will restate again.  When you call get.php?foo=bar&goo=car from a browser, the browser download a file with extension m3u8.  This file is not opened on the screen. I need to preg_replace inside this file then download it.

Comment: @AkshayHedge I appreciate your help.  I am still working on this as time permits.  I am using this code now for file():  ```$file = file('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/get.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);``` Now the php gets processed.  Now I'm working on the regex with preg_grep.  I see the array numbers.  It would probably be more efficient if I could match one line only (less regex comparing), delete that, and delete the following line by array number.  Beyond my pay grade.  I will keep fiddling with preg_grep regex to try and match two lines at once and delete.

Comment: @dyna glad to know that

Answer (score 1):

in PHP you are better off using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) to match lines and remove them, than trying to `shell` -> `grep`

Your question does not have enough information how you expect to match the pattern of the lines you want to remove.

#### Edit

Try this code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('get.php'); /*Receives an m3u file*/
$output = ob_get_contents();
$list = preg_replace('/Remove.*keyphrase.*\n.*\n/' , '' , $output ); /*Also removes the line after the line containing keyphrase*/
echo $list; /*Output as m3u file*/
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It is now updated with preg_replace() and an attempt at matching the example input.

Comment: I updated my answer. The output is now as expected.